# Why is $.getJSON returning ParseError with valid JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to get JSON data from a local file with :

```
$.getJSON(file, function(json_data) {
   console.log(json_data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('getJSON request failed! ' + textStatus); });
```

But despite my *file* is a valid JSON file according to https://jsonlint.com/, I always get the ParseError.

I tried to just get the content with a `$.get(...)` request, but, if I do so, I get an `<empty string>` content.

Could anyone help me ?

Comment: can you post your json file ? or at least use another json validator to see if your file is "really" valid ?

Comment: my file is a valid JSON file:- share file json

Comment: So what is the error message?

Comment: I'd rather it not shared but I get the same error with such a simple file : ```{"a":"b"}```

Comment: @epascarello the alert is : "getJSON request failed! parsererror"

Comment: If `$.get(...)` gives you an empty string, then the file you retrieve might not be what you expect it to be. Inspect your browser network to see if the correct file (including the body) is actually received.

Comment: My guess is you have invisible invalid characters hiding in the file or what you are requesting is not what you think you are. Maybe cached old file. Look at the network request and see what it is. Perform a get and look at the responseText and see what you have. Do something like `console.log(encodeURIComponent(yourXHR.responseText));` and see what is hiding in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
var getProductDataFromJson = new Promise(
  function (resolve) {
     $.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bmehler/product/main/product.json", function(data) { 
         resolve(data);
     });     
  }
);

 getProductDataFromJson
    .then(function (data) {
         console.log('data', data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
         console.log(error.message);
    });
```

This code should work. Just copy my json file and input your data.